# How big is the memory cost when passing an type as parameter to an method?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

For example, I try to do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)compare:(NSDecimal)leftOperand greaterThan:(NSDecimal)rightOperand {
    BOOL returnValue = NO;
    NSComparisonResult result = NSDecimalCompare(&leftOperand, &rightOperand);
    if (result == NSOrderedDescending) { // if the left operand is greater than the right operand
        returnValue = YES;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

But I wonder how big is the cost for memory when using this wrapper. The NSDecimalCompare function takes parameters by reference (is that the word?). But my method does not. I find that by-reference stuff hard to use. Does my method create copies of these values? Is it a waste of memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be making copies of your `NSDecimal`s, but they're only 36-byte (if my math is correct) structs, so it might not be a significant overhead.

But is this really an issue? For example, are you calling this method many times per second? Sample your code first to see where the bottlenecks are before trying to optimize things like this. As Knuth says, "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: Who reads Knuth these days?  I don't know how many times programmers have cited faster processors/big disks/cheap RAM as why Knuth is unnecessary.  Then a platform like the iPhone comes along and StackOverflow becomes the alternative to actually reading Knuth -  and even K&R.